# Batch file to create folder automatically on logon with the date as the file name?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a Batch file that creates a folder automatically on logon with the date as the file name.

I want to create this folder every day to put my everyday stuff on it, so a folder with the date should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Write this command in a file `mkdir %DATE%` and save it as name`.bat`

And to make it run each time computer boots do this

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Once the shortcut has been
   created right-click the file and select Cut.
3. Click Start, Programs,
   right-click the Startup folder and click Open
4. Once the Startup
   folder has been opened click Edit and paste the shortcut into the
   startup. Any shortcuts in the startup folder will automatically
   start each time Windows starts.

Comment: depending on the regional settings, `%DATE%` may contain characters which are not valid as filename.